# Find the term that will have the larger coefficient

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, polynomials

> Which of the expressions $$(1+x^2-x^3)^{100} \textrm{or}\:\: (1-x^2+x^3)^{100}$$ has the larger coefficient of $x^{20}$ after expending abd and collecting terms.

I can easily do this question via multinomial expansion, but here's the twist. In the question it was written to use the hint given to solve the problem. The hint was **replace $-x$ with $x$ to gain extra information.**

I replaced, searched for symmetric properties, odd-even properties but couldn't found any. I'm looking for a solution incorporating the above given hint. Also, if there is any method as easy as ABC to do this, I will also appreciate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map which replaces $x$ with $-x$ doesn't change coefficients of $x^{2n}$ for integers $n$, and so the expressions have the same $x^{20}$ coefficients as
$$(1+x^2+x^3)^{100}\text{ and }(1-x^2-x^3)^{100},$$
respectively. The difference between these two expressions is
$$(1+x^2+x^3)^{100}-(1-x^2-x^3)^{100}=\sum_{n=0}^{100}\binom{100}n(1-(-1)^n)(x^2+x^3)^n,$$
which when fully expanded has no term with negative coefficient, and some terms with positive $x^{20}$ coefficient. So, the first polynomial has a greater $x^{20}$ coefficient than the second.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Ah good catch -- I've fixed the upper bound on the sum.

Comment: I would just note $(1+x^2+x^3)^{100}$ has positive terms which just add up, while $(1-x^2+x^3)^{100}$ would have same terms, but of both signs hence they wouldn't sum to exceed the first. This is a more specific demonstration  though  +1.